# MAUI Firebase iOS not building

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I am trying to implement and compile with Visual Studio 2022 in Windows 11 with push notifications in my MAUI application for both Android and iOS.

I receive the following error when building:

> Unable to copy file "D:\p\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FIRInstallationsErrors.h" to "bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FIRInstallationsErrors.h". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FIRInstallationsErrors.h'

I have already a custom Nuget configuration with a minimal path (D:\p), enabled long paths in the registry and in the 'Local Group Policy Editor'.

Tried to implement `Plugin.Firebase` --> path too long.

Tried to implement `Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging` and `Plugin.Firebase.Core` --> can't build without errors, because the path is too long.

Comment: did u manage to deploy to ios device ? i can build with no errors, but i cant deploy to device. i can only deploy to android.

Comment: I usually don't deploy directly to an iPhone, I use iOS simulators or TestFlight for iOS devices. With TestFlight I can say that It works for my application.

Comment: do you receive your push notification for iOS without any problem ? i can receive push notification for android, but im not receiving any for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It by changing the bin, obj and nuget packages paths to D:\b, D:\o, D:\p.
Now I have installed and implemented Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging and Plugin.Firebase.Core and can compile without problems

Comment: Where do you change those? Is there any other solution except moving everything to the root disk folder?

Comment: You should add a 'Nuget.Config' file where your '*.sln' file is and a 'Directory.Build.props' where your '*.csproj' file is.
In the Nuget config you should specify 'globalPackagesFolder' as D:\p for example.
In the Directory.Build.props you should specify BaseOutputPath and BaseIntermediateOutputPath with relative paths to compile for iOS on a remote mac and on windows for android (for example ..\..\..\b and ..\..\..\o) to point to D:\b and D:\o

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Here :**  *I Have same issue on the Windows machine. while rebuild the android and iOS platform of my project with 286 Error.*

But I'm getting this resolved the One line of code that the TargetFrameworks to Android only when rebuild code on the Windows machine.

**.csproj file add the targetproject to only Android for windows.**

```
**<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;</TargetFrameworks>**
```